# How does 16.04 mount my newly-mdadm-created RAID? (It's not in /etc/fstab)

Tags: mount, raid, fstab, reboot, uuid

I've created a RAID device using mdadm.  It's /dev/md0 and I've successfully formatted and mounted it at /media/raid.  I created an /etc/fstab entry for /dev/md0, but md0 is gone when I reboot.  Upon rebooting, it's mounted at /media/(home dir name) and then the UUID as a folder!  I can't change permissions because it's "mounted", but if I unmount it the folder is gone.

How is it recognizing my raid and mounting it without using /etc/fstab?  If I can find that, I can solve the problem.

I want to change it to non-superuser read/write.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run this:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
update-initramfs -u
```

This makes sure that the RAID device is assembled while booting and is always /dev/md0.